# Threaded proxy checker is slow

Tags: python

I wrote a proxy checker but it was quite slow, so I wanted to make it faster.

```
import requests
import threading

proxies = []
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0","Accept-Encoding": "*","Connection": "keep-alive"}

def getproxies():
  body = requests.get('https://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=getproxies&protocol=http&timeout=1500&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all').text
  cut = body.split('\r\n')
  cut.pop()
  t = threading.Thread(target=check, args=(cut,))
  t.start()

def check(cut):
  for i in cut:
    print('checking ', i)
    if i in proxies:
      print(i, ' is already in the pool')
    else:
      try:
        runner = 'http://{}'.format(i)
        res = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', proxies={'http': runner, 'https': runner}, headers=headers, timeout=1.5)
        if res.status_code == 200:
          print('adding ', i, ' to the pool')
          proxies.append(i)
        else:
          print(i, ' is a bad proxy')
      except Exception as err:
        print(i, ' is a bad proxy')

getproxies()
```

This script is still slow. Can someone help me, but not over-complicate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still running everything on a single thread, it just happens to be a thread you've created rather than the main thread. Nothing changed by doing that. What you need to do is spawn multiple threads with each one handling some subset of the requests you need to make.

Rather than managing the threads yourself you could also, for example, use a worker pool provided by a package such as `multiprocessing`.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer mentions, you're not using threads for anything effective.

Here's a reimplementation using `multiprocessing`, which should be fast.

```
import requests
import multiprocessing

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",
    "Accept-Encoding": "*",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
}


def getproxies():
    resp = requests.get(
        "https://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=getproxies&protocol=http&timeout=1500&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all"
    )
    resp.raise_for_status()
    return set(filter(None, resp.text.splitlines()))


def check_proxy(proxy_addr: str):
    try:
        runner = f"http://{proxy_addr}"
        res = requests.get(
            "https://api.ipify.org?format=json",
            proxies={"http": runner, "https": runner},
            headers=headers,
            timeout=1.5,
        )
        res.raise_for_status()
        print(proxy_addr, " is a good proxy")
        return (proxy_addr, True)
    except Exception as err:
        print(proxy_addr, " is a bad proxy")
        return (proxy_addr, False)


def main():
    proxies = getproxies()
    good_proxies = set()
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
        for proxy_addr, result in p.imap_unordered(check_proxy, proxies, chunksize=8):
            if result:
                good_proxies.add(proxy_addr)
    for proxy_addr in good_proxies:
        print(proxy_addr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: any easier ways to multithread? i dont want to jump in complicated things

Comment: `multiprocessing.map` (and its friends, like `imap_unordered` used here) are the most high-level threading utilities in Python's standard library. How is this complicated in your opinion? Did you read through it?

Comment: of course i read through it. what im trying to ask is if there is a similar way to multithread just with the threading module

Comment: No, there isn't. The threading module is lower level than multiprocessing. If you do want to use threads instead of processes, see multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool.

Comment: Yes, that's manually managing threads; also, you really don't want to create one thread per proxy to check and start them off at the same time, so you'll need a queue of tasks and a thread pool... and then you're back to doing what multiprocessing does.

Comment: well cant you have variable which starts at zero which is used to get the index's value in the list like cut[index] which means threads wont check the same thing

Comment: No, not really. What you'd really want is a `queue.Queue()` for queueing work items and another for their outputs but at that point you're just reimplementing what `multiprocessing` already does for you.

Comment: This code is awesome @AKX